# Filling a dropdown box with multiple columns data from database using Spring is not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I know there are a buch of post related with this out there but none of them have worked for me.

I dont know if what I want to do is easy or no. I am very very new working with Spring.

The aplication is already working and I have to do some modifications, so I want to fill a dropdown box with data requested from a database.

This is my view:

```
<form:form action="${urlcallBankAddAction}" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar(this)" modelAttribute="banco"> 
     <form:select path="descripcion" items="${resultList.descripcion}" />
</form:form>
```

This is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/details", "/details?status={status}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String verBancos(WebRequest request,
        ModelMap model,
        HttpSession session){

    try{
        String valorSesion = (String) session.getAttribute("acceso");//Se valida el inicio de sesion
        if(valorSesion.equals("1")){//Se valida el inicio de sesion
            List<Banco> result = new ArrayList<Banco>();
                            List<String> banksResults = new ArrayList<String>();

            result = bancoService.obtenerTodosLosBancos();                                

            model.addAttribute("currentComponent", "banks.title");
            model.addAttribute("status", request.getParameter("status"));
            model.addAttribute("resultList", result);
                            model.addAttribute("banco", new Banco());
            model.addAttribute("cantidadRegistros", result.size());
            return "details";
        } else{
            //MANDAR A PAGINA DE ERROR
            return "redirect:/unauthorized";
        }
    } catch(NullPointerException n){//Se valida el inicio de sesion
        //MANDAR A PAGINA DE ERROR
        return "redirect:/unauthorized";
    }
}
```

And this is the Model, the sets and gets are there but I Omitted in here:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "cod_visa")
private int codigoVisa;

@Column(name = "CodSud")
private String codigoSudeban;

@Column(name = "descripcion"
```

Something curious about all this is that I already have the data as you can see in the image below, but I only Want to display in my box the description of those clients, the arrow denotes where I want to put my description.

With the current view I got this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "descripcion"
```

And I also tried filling the box with a c:forEach items="${resultList.description} with no result and I used only the "resultList" and then I got the whole object obtained from DB.

[image]

Please help me out with this, I dont know what I am missing or what I am doing wrong. I have faced so many problems with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display the description of every `banco` on your `resultList` use `itemLabel` and `itemValue`, take a look at [Spring documentations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-selecttag):

```
  <form:select path="descripcion" items="${resultLis}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="description"/>
```

It can be done through the `options` tag as well:

```
 <form:select path="descripcion">
  <form:options items="${resultLis}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="description"/>
 </form:select>
```

using JSTL :

```
   <form:select path="descripcion">
    <c:forEach items="${resultList }" var="banco">
        <form:option value="${banco.id }" label="${banco.description }"/>
    </c:forEach>
   </form:select>
```